# How to create a custom Login Form using Laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I want to create a new **Laravel 5.8** based application using the database of an old PHP based application.

The problem is: My previous project uses **five tables** to store user-related information and all of those tables are used during login (to set session data).

Those tables are user_account, user_role, user_partner_portal, user_access_control, and user_control_access_right.

The relationship between those tables are in the below images:

[image]

By default, laravel uses **users** table to handle authentication and I don't know how to customize Laravel login system so that I can use all of those five tables during login to authenticate a user and also store the user-related information into the session.

I am primarily using CodeIgniter for all of my projects and it is very easy to do that authentication using CodeIgniter. But I am new in Laravel, so I can't figure it out.

So my question is: Is it possible using laravel to design such an authentication system? If yes then how?

- TIA

Answer (score 1):

So laravel uses `LoginController` class for the login. Inside there you are going to find the function `authenticate`.

Laravel put's the predefined logic there but if you want to make it really custom like update all your tables etc etc you are free to do it.

You can even create your own class and change the login route to point to your own controller. Basically you can do anything you like.

Comment: In **Laravel 5.8**, there is no **authenticate** method in **LoginController**...

But there is a method **authenticated** in **AuthenticatesUsers** traits. Do you mean that?

Comment: Authenticated method is after the login and retrieved the current authenticated user. There is an authenticate method or a method that your login api points to, you can check that from your rooting(i am using laravel 5.8 and had to modify the same function to make a "custom kinda" login")